# How to autocomplete input based on selection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to autocomplete an input based on a selection. For example if I select `laptop` I want to populate "5677" in an input. Also, if I press `Submit` I'd like to see the raw data of the selection:

```
{
    "Type": "laptop",
    "value": "5677"
}
```

However, I'm getting a nested object like this:

```
{
  "Type": {
    "Type": "laptop",
    "value": "5677"
  }
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/3223/). And here's what I have:

```js
angular
  .module('MdAutocompleteBugApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MdAutocompleteBugController', function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.save = function () {
      console.log($scope.data);
      console.log("dd");
    }

    $scope.datas = [
      {"Type": "Mobile","value": "2400"}, 
      {"Type": "laptop","value": "5677"}, 
      {"Type": "Mobile","value": ""},
      {"Type": "tv",}
    ];

    var elementId = [];

    $scope.newArr = $scope.datas.filter(el => {
      if (elementId.indexOf(el.Type) === -1) {
        elementId.push(el.Type);
        return true;
      }
    });
    $scope.getMatches = function (searchText) {
      var configs = $scope.newArr.filter(function (config) {
        return (config.Type.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchText.toUpperCase()) !== -1);
      });
      return configs;
    }
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="MdAutocompleteBugApp">
  <div ng-controller="MdAutocompleteBugController as vm">
    <form name = "test" ng-submit="save()">
      <md-toolbar class="md-padding">

        <md-autocomplete 
          md-selected-item="data.Type" 
          md-search-text="searchText" 
          md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" 
          md-item-text="item.Type" 
          placeholder="Search states" 
          md-no-cache="true">
          <md-item-template>
            <span>{{item.Type}} </span>
          </md-item-template> 
        </md-autocomplete>

      </md-toolbar><br>

      Value <input type="text" ng-model="data.value"><br><br><br>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to add "md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"" and there we can pass the data to input field and we can get output what ever we want

```
$scope.selectedItemChange = function(item)
{
if(item){
$scope.data.Type = item.Type;
$scope.data.Value = item.Value;
}

}
```